# Socket issues in python with loops

Tags: python

I am trying to code a simple tcp socket code and send multiple times `hello` , but once it sends the first `hello`, it stops , and goes to except

```
try:
    for i in range(0,1024):
        s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8080))
        s.send('Hello')
        s.recv(1024)
except:
    print "Could not connect to 8080 for some reason..."
```

Comment: if you want to send many times then don't connect again or close connection before you connect again.

Comment: your biggest mistake you don't display exception and you don't know where is the problem. So remove `try/except` for a moment or use `except Exception as ex: print('ex:', ex)`

Comment: please post a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What's your question? You can [edit] to clarify. I assume you want to know how to fix it, but it would really help to be explicit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send many times then open it only once - before `for`-loop - and close it only once - after `for`-loop.

```
try:
    s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8080))

    for i in range(1024):
        s.send('Hello')
        s.recv(1024)

    s.close()

except Exception as ex: 
    print('ex:', ex)
```

Eventually close it after sending so you could open it in next loop

```
try:

    for i in range(1024):
        s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8080))
        s.send('Hello')
        s.recv(1024)
        s.close()

except Exception as ex: 
    print('ex:', ex)
```

---

And display exception to see problem's details

```
except Exception as ex: 
    print('ex:', ex)
```